# TextRenderer.DrawText using GDI to render OTF Fonts?

Tags: graphics, gdi+, drawstring, drawtext, textrenderer

I'm trying to draw text over a bitmap image and I've done some research and found that .NET/GDI+ doesn't support OTF fonts. I read somewhere that you could use `TextRenderer.DrawText` to render OTF fonts with GDI, but I can't seem to figure out how, nor does the quality compare to `Graphics.DrawString` in the least bit.

1. First of all, is it possible to use OTF fonts at all in VS or did I read something incorrectly?
2. Second, If the answer is TextRenderer.DrawText, how do I use the OTF fonts? It looks like I have to use the `System.Drawing.Font` class, but I don't think those support the fonts and that's the issue, correct?
3. How do I get the fonts to render clearly like the TTF fonts using GDI+ (`Graphics.DrawString`)
4. Using `Graphics.DrawString` I was able to use a `RectangleF` (with specified width, 0 height) as a boundary for my text, and the text wrapped correctly. With `TextRenderer.DrawText`, the ability to use `RectangleF` disappears and only allows `Rectangle` which doesn't seem to allow 0 height, while still allowing text to display (ie. text must be within the rectangle, and text wrapping does not work). Am I doing it wrong?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. If this cannot be done, is there a way to convert the OTF fonts, or find the Gotham font family online in TTF version? I really need these fonts!

Comment: I ended up using VMware Player to run Ubuntu so I could use [FontForge](http://fontforge.sourceforge.net/) to convert all of my OTF fonts to TTF. Hope this helps anyone with the same problem. Too bad VS isn't compatible with OTF