# How do I get the name of the Font Family given the font file?

Tags: c#, .net, file, fonts, metadata

I have a set of font files with unpredictable filenames, so I can't deduce the real "Font Family" name from the file name. I need to therefore read the font metadata to extract the real "Font Family" name, in order to render this font file. I'm in C#.NET 4.0 WinForms.

I've seen the function `GetFontInformation` but I can't seem to find the P/Invoke headers for the same. All I have is the [C++ version](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI/xfont.aspx) which is honestly hard to figure out. Any ideas?

The reason I cannot use the `PrivateFontCollection` class to parse through a font file for me, is that these are **OTF** fonts and .NET/GDI+ only supports **TTF** fonts!

Comment: If you have a `Font` object you can access the `FontFamily` property: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.font.aspx Will this not work?

Comment: You could try this as well, loading a font file using a file-based Uri: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms602324.aspx

Answer (score 5):

You need to add font to the ([`PrivateFontCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.text.privatefontcollection.aspx)) and then request for the [`FontFamily`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.fontfamily.aspx) and get its `Name` property.

```
private static string GetFontNameFromFile(string filename)
{
    PrivateFontCollection fontCollection = new PrivateFontCollection();
    fontCollection.AddFontFile("path_to_font");
    return fontCollection.Families[0].Name;
}
```

Needed namespace :

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Text;
```

Comment: This method works for **TTF** fonts, but not for **OTF** fonts.

Comment: @Geotarget That's not true. It works for OTF fonts too.

Comment: It does'nt work if you try it. That's impossible because .NET does not support OTF, since GDI+ only supports TTF, or something. http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/557423/Rendering-Text-with-OpenType-Fonts-Using-GDI http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6766670/textrenderer-drawtext-using-gdi-to-render-otf-fonts .. search google : https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1C1CHMO_en-GBIN580IN580&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=.net+gdi+otf+support&spell=1

Comment: I've worked extensively with fonts and I can confirm .NET will not support OTF fonts (or rather, OpenType formatted fonts, sometimes OTF fonts actually have TTF data within, which works)

Comment: Works fine with "FontAwesome.otf", which appears to be an OpenType font.  Specifically, Windows font preview says it contains "PostScript Outlines".  Other fonts have different combinations, for example "GLYPHICONS Halflings" contains "OpenType Layout, TrueType Outlines".

Answer (score 2):

Just open (Double Click) on one of the font files and you will see something like this:-

[image]

Comment: I do not think this is correct. For example, if I open "JetBrains Mono Nerd Font" in Windows, it will show that the name is "JetBrainsMono NFM". Now, if I use "JetBrainsMono NFM" in VSCode, it does not work. If I use "JetBrains Mono Nerd Font" it works.